# Why images are not shown in production environment?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I'm developing a custom mailing template with Odoo docker image (Odoo 14), inheriting mass_mailing module. I placed a thumb image where you choose mailing template when you create a new mailing and also logo of the company in the mailing.

On my local environment, I see the images and everything works well but, when we upload this theme to our production environment and install it, I don't see any of these images. It gives a very common error when I try to open the images.

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

By the way, other than images, all the styles (CSS) that I defined work well.

Do you have any idea why I see the images on my local environment but I don't see them on production environment?

My code:

```html
<template id="custom_email_designer_snippets" inherit_id="mass_mailing.email_designer_snippets" name="Custom E-mail designer snippets">
  <xpath expr="//div[@id='email_designer_themes']" position="inside">
    <div data-name="custom_template" title="Custom Mailing Template" data-img="/mass_mailing_themes_custom/static/src/img/theme_imgs/custom_thumb" data-images-info='{"logo": {"format": "png"}}'>
      <t t-call="mass_mailing_themes_custom.theme_custom_template"/>
    </div>
  </xpath>
</template>
<template id="theme_custom_template">
  <t t-call="mass_mailing.s_mail_block_paragraph"/>
  <t t-call="mass_mailing.s_mail_block_footer_separator"/>
  <img src="/mass_mailing_themes_custom/static/src/img/theme_custom_1/logo_grey_120x41.png" width="60" alt="Logo grey"/>
</template>
```

Comment: looking at the error thrown, I think the image is not found on the server.  Check if the image is in production environment, just not in the development environment.

Comment: We have just found the reason. The problem was file permissions. So, the images were already there but without public permission.